# I did get sick of having hot coffee and blood thrown at me - Help with its meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

On the show Schitts'Creek, there is a sentence: "I did get sick of having hot coffee and blood thrown at me." I don't really get the meaning of "blood thrown at me". Please kindly help me to clarify it.

The full dialogue is below:
https://tvquot.es/schitts-creek/quote/7n2vw9s

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a fur coat. There is an urban myth that some animal rights activists try to discourage people from wearing furs by attacking them in public by throwing blood at them. The speaker in your dialogue may be echoing that myth. (And the *hot coffee* could be another example of such aggression, if the attacker didn't happen to have any blood with them in the moment.)

[about fur](https://blog.truthaboutfur.com/will-red-paint-be-thrown-on-me-if-i-wear-fur/)

> There’s a common misconception that if you wear fur in public, you’ll get red paint or pig’s blood thrown on you. This is an urban myth that’s been around for decades, and we are here to reassure you that it will not happen!